# Error: dlmForecast only works with constant models for dlmForecast() in R package "dlm"

Tags: r, time-series

I have a simple time series matrix, X is a matrix of economic indicator (62*4). In the matrix, The respondent is interest rate, the other 3 covriates are CPI, GDP and stock market return. I want to do dynamic linear model forecast of interest rate with multi covariates (CPI,GDP,Stock market return) using dlmForecast() in dlm package of R. but I am stuck with an error "dlmForecast only works with constant models".

```
imod<-dlmModReg(X)
n<-nrow(X)
m<-nrow(imod$FF)
p<-ncol(X)+1
W(imod) <- rwishart(2*p,p) * 1e-1
m0(imod) <- rnorm(p, sd=5)
C0(imod) <- diag(p) * 1e-1
new <- 100
str(imod)
fore <- dlmForecast(imod, nAhead=n, sampleNew=new)
```